# JQuery syntax - hover not working on infinite scroll pages

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, jquery-hover

I'm using the infinite-ajax-scroll plugin (https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll) along with the Hover Caption plugin (http://ryun.github.io/HCaptions/).  The hover effect works well on the first page, however it isn't applied to the pages loaded via the infinite scroll plugin.

I have read that using .on() instead of .hover() should work and have also tried the .scroll() event.  However, I can't seem to get anything working without amending the code within the plugins which isn't ideal.

What event should I be detecting to activate the hcaption plugin and how do I write this?

My code below:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

     //hcaptions for mouseover tiles  
     $('.hcaption').hcaptions({
         effect: "slide",
         direction: "bottom"
     });

     //isotope
     var $container = $('#container'),
         filters = {};
     $container.isotope({
         itemSelector: '.element, .element_tile',

     });    

     // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
     jQuery.ias({
         container: '#main', // main container where data goes to append
         item: '.element', // single items
         pagination: '.paginate', // page navigation
         next: '.paginate a', // next page selector
         loader: '<img src="public/img/ajax-loader.gif"/>', // loading gif
         loaderDelay: 200,
         thresholdMargin: -600,
         noneleft: 'No more discounts', //Contains the message to be displayed when there are no more pages left to load
         triggerPageThreshold: '10', // show "load more" if scroll more than this to stop
         trigger: "",
         onLoadItems: function (newElements) {
             // hide new items while they are loading
             var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
                 opacity: 0
             });
             // ensure that images load before adding to isotope layout
             $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
                 // show elems now they're ready
                 $newElems.animate({
                     opacity: 1
                 });
                 $container.isotope('insert', $newElems, true);
             });
             return true;
         }
     });
 });

 </script>
```

Section of code from hcaption.js that possibly needs overwriting:

```
        $target.css('z-index',opts.zindex+1).hide();
        $wrap.hover(function () {
            $target.stop(true, true).fadeIn(+opts.speed, opts.onshow());
        }, function () {
            $target.stop(true, true).fadeOut(+opts.speed, opts.onhide());
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize the Hover Caption plugin on your new elements once they're loaded, using the `onRenderComplete` hook in the Infinite Ajax Scroll plugin..

I've set up a JSFiddle and Gist to simulate the Infinite Scroll along with HCaptions to show you what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/nate/9JGTV/1/

```
$('.hcaption').hcaptions();

var iterator = 0;

$.ias({
    container : '.listing',
    item: '.post',
    pagination: '.navigation',
    next: '.next-posts a',
    triggerPageThreshold: 10,

    // You should not need this! This is purely to make
    // it possible to view repeated pages on JSFiddle,
    // since each hcaption requires a unique ID.
    onLoadItems: function (items) {
        $(items).each(function (i, item) {
            $(item).find('.hcaption')
              .removeAttr('data-target')
              .attr('data-target', 'tog-' + iterator);

            $(item).find('.cap-overlay')
              .removeAttr('id')
              .attr('id', 'tog-' + iterator);

            iterator += 1;
        });
    },

    // This is the important bit --
    // reinitialize hcaptions on the new items.
    onRenderComplete: function (items) {
        $(items).find('.hcaption').hcaptions();
    },
    loader: '<img src="http://placehold.it/100x50/333333/ffffff/&text=LOADING..."/>'
});
```

There are two important things to note:

- You have to use `onRenderComplete`, not `onLoadItems`, or the hcaptions won't work correctly. I suspect that the plugin makes calculations based on the rendered sizes of the items it uses, which means those sizes are wrong if it gets triggered before they're in the DOM.
- hcaptions rely on unique `id`s for every item. That's kind of a weird limitation - it's not the way I would write the plugin, but, whatevs. So you need to make sure that every new item you load has a unique `data-target` and `id`. For my example, I had to do some extra manipulating of the new items in the `onLoadItems` hook to give them unique `id`s that you shouldn't need to worry about.

Comment: That works but only on the 2nd page.  On page 3 onwards I encounter the same issue where it is not applied...hmmm..

Comment: Actually it behaves really odd.  It doesn't apply the hover on the 2nd page of items until the 3rd page is loaded.  The items on the 3rd page don't have the hover until the 4th page is loaded.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle that duplicates your problem? That would make it much easier for us to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help with this.  im trying to get the infinite-scroll to work without server side paging in JSfiddle.  Will post if  manage to get something working :\

Comment: Making a standalone example turned out to be kinda non-trivial, since it relied on server-side paging, as you said. It was an interesting challenge, so I went ahead and did it, using JSFiddle's Gist integration, which is really cool. I've updated my answer. Hopefully you can see this example working and use it as a reference to get your own example working.

Comment: Thats fantastic!  Thank you so much your trouble and effort!